# What's the logic behind the fake/real computer chip?

Tags: plot-explanation, now-you-see-me-2

So in Now You See Me 2, after the Horsemen steal the computer chip that Walter Mabry wanted, Daniel goes to the market to try to hand over the chip to someone from the Eye, but it turns out he was tricked by Walter. He's cornered and ordered to give it up, but Dylan cuts in and saves him.

Dylan gets beaten up and half-drowned, but the Horsemen save him. Right then, Jack says the chip is a fake. Then there's a whole scene where they're discussing what to do and how they could suddenly have a fake chip, and how they lost the real one.

But later, on the plane, Daniel is coerced into giving Walter the chip, which turns out to be real again. So was it real the whole time? Or was it switched with a fake, and right up till the end, the Horsemen were still pretending it was real? And if so, where did the real one go?

Comment: I totally didn't get that part either, but by then I had lost all sense of logic so just bought it without giving it any thought.

Comment: I actually watched it twice to understand the whole plot, but that was the only part I didn't understand...